# C# HTTP Server Access Denied

Tags: c#, networking, server, permissions, ip

So I'm making a local server on my pc with C#. The server responds and works fine when I run it on `http://localhost:8000`, however when trying to use it on the LAN IP address  `http://192.168.1.113:8000`, it gives me an access error.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.HttpListenerException' occurred in System.Net.HttpListener.dll: 'Access is denied.'
   at System.Net.HttpListener.AddPrefixCore(String registeredPrefix)
   at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()
   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
   at HttpListenerExample.HttpServer.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\abram\Desktop\Code\C#\myProgram\Program.cs:line 100
```

I've tried making a URL reservation: `netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8000/myProgram user=abram`

This worked to no avail.
Anyone experienced in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow port **8000** through Windows Firewall.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you reserve in your call to `netsh http add urlacl` needs to match exactly the prefix you are adding to your `HttpListener`. And `HttpListener` prefixes need to end in a slash. So your code should look something akin to this:

```cs
httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:8000/myProgram/");
```

And your command should look like this:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8000/myProgram/ user=abram
```

If you make any change to either URI, you need to reflect that change in the command.

> You'll also want to ensure that `abram` is a valid user on the domain/machine.

Also, you might want to check out [Grapevine 5](https://github.com/scottoffen/grapevine) for running a local server.